# Matlab: make predictions with SVM for multiclass classification problems

Tags: matlab, svm, multiclass-classification

I am trying to use a Support Vector Machine to classify my data in 3 classes. I used this Matlab function to train and cross-validate the SVM:

```
Mdl = fitcecoc(XTrain, yTrain, 'Learners', 'svm', 'ObservationsIn', 'rows', ...
   'ScoreTransform', 'invlogit','Crossval','on', 'Holdout', 0.2);
```

where XTrain contains all of my data and yTrain is a cell containing the names of each class to be assigned to the input data in XTrain.
The function above returns to me:

```
Mdl --> 1x1 ClassificationPartitionedECOC
```

My question is, what function do I have to use in order to make predictions using new data? In the case of binary classification, I build the SVM with 'fitcsvm' and then I predicted the labels with:

```
[label, score] = predict(Mdl, XTest);
```

However, if I feed the ClassificationPartitionedECOC to the 'predict' function, it gives me this error:

```
No valid system or dataset was specified.
```

I haven't been able to find a function that allows me to perform prediction starting from the model format that I have, ClassificationPartitionedECOC.
Thanks for any help you may provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the learner `i` through:

`Mdl.BinaryLearners{i}`

Because `fitcecoc` just trains a binary classifier like you would do with `fitCSVM` in a one versus one fashion.

Comment: Are you telling that the Mdl.BinaryLearners{i} is the same as the predict function?

Comment: use `predict(Mdl.BinaryLearners{i}, XTest)`